# Unicode: English characters above code point 127

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

I'm giving a tech talk about Unicode and encoding in my company, in which I'm trying to make the point that [strings are always encoded](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), and developers should never carelessly assume that everything is 0-127 ASCII.

I have numerous examples of problems caused by mis-encoded text, but I didn't find any example of simple English text with numbers that's encoded above Unicode [code point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) 127.

The basic English alphabet is mapped in Unicode to the same numerical value as the plain old ASCII: The range `A-Z` is mapped to `[65-90]` (or `[0x41-0x5a]` in hex), and `[a-z]` is mapped to `[97-122]` (hex `[0x61-0x7a]`).

**Does the English alphabet appear elsewhere in the code charts?** I do not mean [circumflex letters or other Latin variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1_Controls_and_Latin-1_Supplement), just the plain English alphabet.

Comment: *"Strings should always be encoded and never treated as plain text"?!* Sorry, that's hardly makes sense. Strings [*are always encoded*](http://kunststube.net/encoding/), even if they're plain text. Maybe you can clarify what you meant?

Comment: Of course. I meant that developers should always bear in mind that Strings are encoded, and they should never treat a string as "Plain Text".

Comment: Fixed my question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Well, "plain text" is still "plain text". You should just never assume the encoding to be something it mightn't be.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your point.

Comment: これは「プレインテキスト」。 <- This is plain text. But it's plain text encoded in UTF-8. The two are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: I think in this context "treating something as plain text" means braindead code that is unaware of anything but US-ASCII. Plain text normally means files that are human-readable as is, as opposed to binary/rich-text files which require processing.

Comment: Do ｆｕｌｌｗｉｄｔｈ　ｃｈａｒａｃｔｅｒｓ　count? They aren't really used outside of CJK texts, but they may still fit your criteria.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen English full width characters? Yes, they count - could you please send a link?

Comment: @AdamMatan: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms), [Unicode code chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFF00.pdf). Again, keep in mind these are almost exclusively used in conjunction with actual CJK text.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen I will love to accept this as an answer - could you please post it as one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CJK characters are generally monospaced in all fonts, since that's how those languages tend to be written.

When mixing CJK and English characters, however, you run into a problem: ASCII characters do not in general have the width of a CJK character. This means that if you use ASCII, you lose the monospaced property - which may not always be desirable.

For this purpose, ｆｕｌｌｗｉｄｔｈ　ｃｈａｒａｃｔｅｒｓ (U+FF00-FFEE, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms), [Unicode code chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFF00.pdf)) may be used in place of "regular" characters. These have the property that they have the same width as a single CJK character.

Note, however, that fullwidth characters are virtually never used outside of a CJK context, and even in those contexts, plain ASCII is frequently used as well, when monospacing is considered unimportant.

Comment: CJK stands for Chinese Japanse Korean, had to look that up :P

Comment: Thanks again! I gave the tech talk today and this example knocked everybody off.

Answer (score 3):

Plenty of punctuation and symbols have code point values above U+007F:

> - “Hello.”
> - He had been given the comprehensive sixty-four-crayon Crayola box—including the gold and silver crayons—and would not let me look.
> - x ≠ y

The above examples use:

- U+201C and U+201D — smart quotes
- U+2014 — em-dash
- U+2260 — not equal to

See the [Unicode charts](http://unicode.org/charts/) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you just mean `a-z` and `A-Z` then no, there are no English characters above 127. But words like `fiancé`, `resumé` etc are sometimes spelled like that in English and use codepoints above 127.

Then there are various punctuation signs, currency symbols and so on that are above 127. Not sure if this counts as simple English text.

Comment: My example was `Häagen-Dazs`. Thanks for the examples!

Comment: Naïve, coördination, smörgåsbord, Ångström.  All of these are loan words, of course.  Curiously, companies like Skånska and Strömberg often drop the diacritics from their name in international correspondence (even to the point of changing the company name, in the case of Skånska).